# Android: Can we even "design" our own widgets and layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout, widget, android-view, android-viewgroup

I read this here:

> **Android provides a number of ready-made views** that you can use to
>   design and organize your layout. "Widgets" are views that provide a
>   visual (and interactive) elements for the screen, such as a button,
>   text field, checkbox, or just an image. "Layouts" are views derived
>   from ViewGroup that provide a unique layout model for its child views,
>   such as a linear layout, a grid layout, or relative layout. **You can
>   also subclass the View and ViewGroup classes (or existing subclasses)
>   to create your own widgets and layouts and apply them to your activity
>   layout.**

If I am not wrong, this means people can even *design* their own widgets and layouts? Does that ever happen? Any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this means people can even design their own widgets and layouts?

Yes.

> Does that ever happen?

Yes.

> Any examples?

There are hundreds of examples out on [the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) alone. Just looking at a couple of columns of the recent items, there are the following custom widgets and containers:

- [`material-drawer`](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1162)
- [Material Design Android Library](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1156)
- [StarBar](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1153)
- [AndroidProgressLayout](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1175)
- [DiscreteSeekBar](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1172)
- [Android-SingleInputForm](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1163)
- [SunDate Picker](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1159)